# Checkbox remains checked when setting IsChecked to false in ViewModel (MVVM WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a binding between a view (MainView) and view model (MainViewModel) with a checkbox as part of a data template (StaticDataItemTemplate). It looks like this:
[image]

I want to uncheck all checked checkboxes when clicking New Tag, and I have setup a command to set the IsChecked property for each Studio (in an Observable Collection of studios) to false when this is clicked. This is happening but the boxes remain checked on the UI and I cannot figure out why.

Data Template (StaticDataItemTemplate) where the checkboxes are defined (excluding the buttons):

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StaticDataItemDataTemplate">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

How the StaticDataItemTemplate is used in the main window:

```
<Expander Header="Studios">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ListBox MaxHeight="150" x:Name="StaticDataListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Studios}"
                                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudio}"
                             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StaticDataItemDataTemplate}"
                             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
                            <TextBox AcceptsReturn="False" Text="{Binding StudioToAdd, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                <TextBox.InputBindings>
                                    <KeyBinding 
                                    Key="Enter" 
                                    Command="{Binding AddStudioCommand}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}" />
                                </TextBox.InputBindings>
                            </TextBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Expander>
```

Clear tag command (which is supposed to clear all checkboxes) in main window xml:

```
<MenuItem Header="_New Tag"
                          Command="{Binding ClearTagCommand}"/>
```

In Main Window View Model, clear tag command triggers on new tag method with following code:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
        {

            this.AddFileCommand = new RelayCommand(OnAddFile);
            this.SaveTagCommand = new RelayCommand(OnSaveTag);
            this.ClearTagCommand = new RelayCommand(OnNewTag); 
...
 private void OnNewTag()
        {
            foreach(var actor in Actors)
            {
                actor.IsChecked = false;
            }
            foreach (var studio in Studios)
            {
                studio.IsChecked = false;
            }
            foreach (var category in Categories)
            {
                category.IsChecked = false;
            }
```

But issue is that OnNewTag does set IsChecked to false, but values don't update on the view. I have implement INPC like so:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { }; 
...

public ObservableCollection<Studio> Studios
        {
            get
            {
                return studios;
            }

            set
            {
                if (studios != value)
                {
                    studios = value;
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Studios"));
                }
            }
        }
```

Finally, the Studios class looks like so:

```
public class Studio
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int StudioId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Ignore]
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

        public Studio()
        {

        }

        public Studio(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            IsChecked = false; 
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Implement INPC in `Studio` class, and raise PropertyChanged event in IsChecked setter

Comment: I've been stuck on this for a week, thank you!